# Create dictionary comprehension from os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a dictionary of all mp3 files where the key is the mp3 filename and the value is the filepath for that file.

I do:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown='true'):
    source_files_now = {filename:root for filename in files if filename[-4] == '.mp3'}
    print(source_files_now);
```

But the dictionary, source_files_now ends up being empty.

There are definetly mp3 files in the directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`filename[-4] == '.mp3'` checks whether the third-to-last character is `'.mp3'`. That doesn't really make sense.

Just use `.endswith()`:

```
filename.endswith('.mp3')
```

If you want to fix your code, slice the string so that the slice includes the other characters:

```
filename[-4:] == '.mp3'
```

I'd also convert the filename to lowercase before comparing it. You might end up skipping filenames that are in all caps.

Comment: @mgilson can you give me a code snippet or send me a link and tell me why fromKeys is better?

Comment: or use `os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == 'mp3'`

Comment: @isedev: I never really understood what that method is for. Is there any reason to use that instead of using `.endswith` or `filename.split('.')[-1]?

Comment: or `os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in {'mp3','MP3'}` ... etc, etc.

Comment: @Blender -- I think it's for obscure systems where `.` isn't the extension separator.  I think it probably uses [`os.extsep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.extsep) to split the string

Comment: @isdev -- But, if you use `.endswith('mp3')`, you're still safe -- Unless you have files named `foo.mymp3` I guess ...

Comment: @isedev The {1, 2, 3} is s set comprehension.

Comment: @isedev you might need a .mp3 and not a mp3. That's what you need with python 3.x on python.

Comment: @JCash -- Technically, it's a set literal -- `{x for x in iterable}` is a set comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [-4] issue already mentioned, you keep overwriting source_files_now in your for loop. Initialize it above the loop and just add to it instead of using the dict comprehension.

```
source_files_now = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.mp3'):
            source_files_now[filename] = os.path.join(root, filename)
```

It doesn't break your script, but it should be topdown=True, not topdown='true'. I removed it because True is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You index the string slightly wrong:

```
>>> s = 'buddyholly.mp3'
>>> s[-4]
'.'
>>> s[-4:]
'.mp3'
```